# Exception returned when inserting into table through ASP.NET 3.5 C# method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I have a method that sends two variables, an int and a delimited string, to an SQL Server proc.

Variable values (copied from debugger):

```
detailId: 5
fileNames: "recruiter.txt|cert.pdf"
```

The method:

```
public void InsertFiles(int detailId, string fileNames)
{
    ConnectionStringSettings connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PRADB"];
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString.ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.InsertFiles";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@detailId", detailId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileNames", fileNames);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exc = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertFiles]
@detailId int,
@fileNames varchar(max)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

insert into [dbo].[PRA_Files] (detailId, fileNames)
     values (@detailId, @fileNames)
END
```

The exception received when debugging:

```
{"Incorrect syntax near 'dbo'."}
```

Yet when I execute from the proc:

```
exec [dbo].[InsertFiles] 5, "recruiter.txt|cert.pdf"
```

It works fine.  There error isn't code side as it is being caught in the catch block of the method above.  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify that the command is a stored procedure:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.InsertFiles";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@detailId", detailId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileNames", fileNames);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Ah you just beat me to it. :-)

Comment: Was about to post the same thing. Caught me out so many times that one ;)

Comment: doh.  Thanks D.  Hate the simple mistakes,  can never find them.